# Desk(s) configuration problem

Tags: home, office, furniture, desk

I'm moving to a new house and getting new office furniture. I am a computer programmer and audio engineer. This means that I need multiple computers, large speakers, and 2-4 screens on my desk(s). I like having room to write on paper on the desk and I also like standing at my work desk when programming.

Here are some problems I've run into trying to decide what to get:

- If I get a standing desk, it won't fit all the speakers and screens since most standing desks are pretty small.
- If I get a big right angle desk I can't stand, even though it has enough room
- I've used a little "riser" before to put my screen up high and stick stuff under it, but that was on a sitting desk and the high monitor never felt right.

Is there a massive standing desk that I just can't find online (the largest I see are about 30 x 70 inches)? Or is it possible to have some kind of large angle desk with "standing attachments" of some kind? Has anyone made two standing desks at right angles work?

Comment: If 30x70 inches is small, will you please tell us what size you actually need / want?

Comment: Are you aware of rise-and-fall desks, where an electric mechanism varies the height of the desk to your requirement?

Comment: There are also "standing desk converters" that you can place on a larger sitting desk, where you can put your main 2 screens and keyboard, and then switch between positions at will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the monitors 'fit' above a small desk:

Don't use the feet they came with. Attach the monitors to a [monitor arm](https://www.walmart.com/c/kp/monitor-arms). The arm is attached to the desk at one point, so you can have the monitors stick out over the sides of the desk. 
This also allows you to shove the keyboard and mouse underneath the monitors when you're not using them, freeing up space for writing etc.

If you have separate computers for your programming and audio needs, consider putting them on separate desks:

- an audio desk with your DAW, and speakers in the optimum position flanking one large monitor
- an adjustable desk for programming with multiple monitors

A quick search finds [this 80x30" desk](https://www.upliftdesk.com/uplift-v2-standing-desk-v2-or-v2-commercial/?product_config=4853) and this [L-shaped desk with 2 80" arms](https://www.upliftdesk.com/uplift-v2-l-shaped-standing-desk/). I used these [search terms.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=standing%20desk%20L-shape)

Comment: @JacobIRR: you accepted an answer which is not obviously related to your question. You asked about huge desks, while the answer is about arms for monitors. Will you please explain your choice? I am just curious. I guess that the length of table (from left to right) still needs to fit the combined width of the monitors. How are the arms going to make the table longer? Do you plan to attach (e.g.) 6 monitors to one small desk, using arms?

Comment: Did you read the last sentence of my answer?

Answer (score 3):

I really think that in your case, several independent desks are a better option. You will surely not do audio editing while becoming the next Shakespeare writing stuff on paper.

What I would do (and I am on the way of implementing it for my own needs):

- understand which are the activities I have to do;
- understand which resources (computers, monitors, paper, chairs...) are needed for each activity;
- if at all possible, group things that go together, and separate those which do not;
- decide which kind of table is suitable for each activity / area better.

In the end, you can choose to buy identical desks, or different - which might help you keep the costs down also. An added benefit of different desks is that you can alternate between standing and sitting.

Note: 30"x70" is pretty much the maximum size you can get from one sheet. The wooden boards which are used to build the desks come in certain sizes, and what you found already is close to the maximum limit. To have something bigger, several sheets have to be joined together somehow.

Note2: you can go into designing the desks yourself, and have them custom build at some local shop. Or build them yourself, if you are into it, and the design is not very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

**Custom Make** Your Solution

When I wanted an inclined drawing table 20'X 3', that was attached to the wall (no legs to get in the way of cleaning) with convenient shelving over it; I hired a contractor.

A contractor can make exactly what you specify to fit in your available space to make your life much easier. In addition, a professional cabinet maker (my choice) made suggestions based on years of experience that I never would have thought of having until after the fact. I added the various chairs, and equipment necessary for my work and started the day after construction ended. Most of the work was made by the contractor in their factory and pre-fab assembled in a few hours at my location.

If some existing furniture design does what you want in the way that you want, it can be incorporated into the room design or (better) copied and resized for your exact application.

I was able to make everything in my studio ergonomic for optimal efficiency and comfort.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you put 2 sit stand desks together. 1 left 1 right.  With the controls at the middle,  would that fit the space?
https://www.ikea.com/ca/en/p/bekant-corner-desk-left-sit-stand-linoleum-blue-black-s89282280/